# Too fast upvote on an answer?

Tags: discussion, voting

I just posted an answer to a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51035246), and I almost immediately got an upvote. I'm talking ~20 sec from me posting the answer.

It's not a long or complex answer, but at ~200 words and a couple of links, assuming an [average read speed of ~200 English words per minute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_per_minute#Reading_and_comprehension) (and I would assume that for technical texts written by a non-native on the language, and possibly also read by a non-native, this speed could be quite slower), I find hard to believe that someone was able to read my answer, verify if it makes any sense, and choose to upvote it.

**Questions:**

- Is this normal behavior?
- AFAIK, I'm not in any sockpuppet ring or anything. Should I be worried?
- Do moderators have checks for these things? (Instant upvotes)
- Would it make sense to have the upvote button disabled for, let's say, words-in-answer/1000 minutes?

  - This would force you to read, at least, 1/5 of the answer.
  - A small hover message could appear saying "Are you sure you want to upvote? You're a fast reader!"

I'm not complaining about receiving upvotes on my answers, but I don't want irrelevant/unjustified upvotes. The whole point of having the upvote system is to be sure that answers make sense, and upvoting without even reading could negatively impact the quality of the relevant answers, which would affect the community as a whole.

Comment: *You get an upvote, you get an upvote, you get an upvote and you get an upvote ... EVERYBODY gets an upvote* ... welcome on upvote Tuesday ...

Comment: ohh this is nice,
one who complains because he takes upvotes too soon ... well it means you asked a good question!

I would also like to ask some nice questions from 2000 points... :(

Comment: You should be wary of 'Downvote Thursday' :)

Comment: Yes, it is normal. There are robo voters voting everything which moves, blatantly wrong answers get upvotes, questions asking for an address in some winklandia get upvotes, no matter what the content is, everything get upvotes. Probably badge hunters, but sometimes also participants of a voting ring, or trolls.

Comment: @rene I did not receive any upvote today, where should I apply? Is there a form to fill?

Comment: Show this when someone complaint about SO being rude.

Comment: @il_raffa yes, that must be a bug, use the contact us form at the bottom of the page to stalk SE staff ...

Comment: @il_raffa Ticket Resolved.

Comment: I checked asker's profile, they seem to be not quite experienced and they have rep over 15 points - meaning they could upvote out of pure gratitude. Since askers are notified about answers thay could do that in 20 seconds. Or they even could be looking at the question right at the moment you posted and notice it

Comment: You know, it could simply be that someone just read the title and found the question interesting. Interesting questions are often up-voted.

Comment: well you could balance the vote out by giving me a free upvote ;)

Comment: Totally disappointing possibility: someone did it by accident. I sometimes do when I'm using a trackpad on a laptop, its easier than you would think.

Comment: @rene, I didn't. What's wrong with the system?

Comment: @Victoria as usual it is off by 6 to 8 votes and/or caching or both ...

Comment: Not going to lie, there have been times (*dark days*) when I simply read a question (it took me 10 secs to read that one) and if it appears valid and at least somewhat well-written: I'll upvote it just because it released me from the dark cloud that other questions that day had put me in. Sometimes with the thought that if a re-read shows it to be not worth the upvote I can remove it.

Comment: @ManojKumar **Voting has nothing to do with being welcoming**.

Comment: There's been times in the past where I've written out an answer, or am halfway through doing so, and then "1 new answer" pops up. I read it and see that it's virtually identical to what I was going to post, so I upvote and abandon my own answer. IMO this is a legitimate reason/use case for an upvote appearing within the first few seconds of an answer being posted.

Comment: This isn't relevant to that particular answer, but it's also possible to get votes on answers by accident. If your answer appears just as someone's about to vote on the previous top answer they may accidentally click on yours instead. Most of the time when that happens, people notice they've made a mistake and reverse the vote, but not always.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

If I have a practically ready made answer in my mind, just about to create one and then I see an answer coming up, it might take me less than half a minute to scan it for exactly the details I have already prepared.
If I see them I might upvote, judging that the answer is definitely good, because it is exactly what I wanted to say (slightly vain, I admit), give or take a few typos, grammar errors and even minor inaccuracies.
Not saying that acting like that is perfect, but it does give a reasonably justified upvote in extremely short time.

Comment: That is actually a pretty good point. I noticed the question pop-up on the new questions tab, so it's likely that more people were already looking at it. This is supported by the fact that shortly after, a new (valid and different) answer appeared in the question.

Comment: "it might take me less than half a minute to scan it for exactly the details I have already prepared" <-- Twice I've had others drop in on questions (not with votes but with comments) showing a lack of having read the entire question. They were both about esoteric stuff, but it concerns me that we are primed to upvote/downvote/comment and move on before finishing reading. I imagine this is a side-effect of the number of low quality questions, but it's discouraging. Note: I'm not suggesting that's the case here, just making an observation.

Comment: That's true @JonHarper I've often clicked on new questions only seconds after they have been posted and saw comments and answers popping up before I even finished reading the question.

Comment: @JohnHarper I fully agree, answering before reading the question completely is evil. I am honest enough to admit that I have succumbed to that particular temptation in the past. But I have either noticed myself and deleted the comment/answer, or in many cases have been (more or less politely but usually absolutely deservedly) been called out on it and *then* deleted the stupid comment/answer. However, we also agree that this question here describes not reading an **answer** completely, don't we?

Comment: This scenario does appear to match the context of the vote - the voter had an answer partially composed and loaded Jofre's answer via the real-time notification.  FWIW.

Comment: @Shog9 Sorry, I do not get your point. I do not understand which scenario you refer to and not who the voter is, or on what they votes, since obviously they are anonymous.

Comment: I'm saying I checked the logs (as I tend to do for complaints about odd voting behaviors) and based on that the scenario you describe is likely what happened here, @Yunnosch.

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks for clarifying. That I understand. Also seems quite obvious now...

Comment: @Yunnosch It's much the same though, is it not? Things like poor English, lack of capitalization prime us to downvote, while lots of quotes and code blocks prime us to upvote. There are quite a few highly voted answers that look great and are largely incorrect. If an answer is about a subject we are unfamiliar with, how long before the, "eh, it looks right" factor comes in to play and results in an unguided upvote?

Comment: @JonHarper Apart from "I really try hard not to." I have to agree, sadly. It might be worth making a question here on meta, "What **should** make us (up)vote?" (Apart from the bubble help on the vote buttons.) Anybody knows a duplicate?

Comment: Took me way less than 20 seconds to verify and upvote this answer for exactly the reason described in the answer. Wow, this is really Meta!

Answer (score 15):

There are some users who up-vote all the answers which they receive to their own questions. I personally know a few of them. So if that is the case, you can receive an up-vote even within 5 seconds, but I don't recommend that behaviour.

Comment: There are even users that actively brag about doing this.  I've seen several people write as much on their profiles.  The behavior is abhorrent, but certainly does happen.

Comment: Given the number of users on SO, this must be true. No idea why it's downvoted. This is not a "do you agree with this" poll, right...

Comment: there are _a lot_ of users upvoting answers to their questions just to thank the users who answered, no matter the contents. acceptance is limited, though, to leave a chance to other answers to better the current one